# where does the downloaded data store while we use emulator browser of android

Tags: android, download, emulation

I am using android emulator to access internet and download some pictures through it. where does it store the data which was downloaded by it? I am able to see the downloading icon on the top of the emulator.Can u any let me know about it.

Comment: Check in Downloads directory in sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

it is saved in your Android Virtual Device. Open the directory where you created your aVD and scan there. For more information i recommend reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html)